# Get Windows version with Java is not working

Tags: java, string, get, operating-system, int

I have a code which is supposed to get the current OS version, so lets say the computer I use, is running Windows 10 then it would output 10. The code in theory should work, but there is a slight problem. The code itself does not give any errors, but whenever I run it I get the console error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10.0"

I am not completely sure where my code is wrong, but there is definitely something which is not connecting.

### Here is the code

```
private static String OSV = System.getProperty("os.version").toLowerCase();
static int OSVnum = Integer.parseInt(OSV);


    static void windRoc() throws IOException {

            if (OSVnum == 10.0) {
                System.out.println("It is working!");
            } else if (OSVnum == 7) {
                stop1();
            } else {
                stop2();
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently trying to parse a floating point number as an integer, which doesn't work.  Instead, try using `Double.parseDouble`:

```
static double OSVnum = Double.parseDouble(OSV);
```

Then make your checks as you were previously:

```
static void windRoc() throws IOException {
    if (OSVnum == 10.0) {
        System.out.println("It is working!");
    } else if (OSVnum == 7) {
        stop1();
    } else {
       stop2();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is now working like I wanted it to. Your help is much appreciated.